# Files in package libfftw3-dev don't match file list

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install the package [libfftw3-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libfftw3-dev). I install it via command line and then try to locate the files from the package (it may not show all the dependencies being installed because I uninstalled and reinstalled to show this):

```
$sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libfftw3-bin
Suggested packages:
   libfftw3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 183 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,136 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package libfftw3-bin.
(Reading database ... 715638 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfftw3-bin_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfftw3-bin (3.3.4-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfftw3-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfftw3-dev_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfftw3-dev:amd64 (3.3.4-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libfftw3-bin (3.3.4-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libfftw3-dev:amd64 (3.3.4-2ubuntu1) ...
```

Then I try to locate the files:

```
$ locate fftw3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so.3.4.4
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3/README
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3/README
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-long3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-long3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.shlibs
```

The shared objects installed correctly, but comparing the list with the [filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libfftw3-dev/filelist) for the package, there is a lot of stuff missing, such as the files I really need, the headers and pkg-config files. I'm really confused what is going on here and why I would not have all the files that are supposed to come in this package.

Comment: `locate` doesn't perform a real disk search but only a database lookup in some kind of file name database. This database gets updated automatically every now and then (daily IIRC), but you should trigger an update manually using `sudo updatedb` after adding new or removing old files to get correct and up to date results.

Comment: @ByteCommander, I see that was it. After updating the files are exactly where they are supposed to be.

Comment: Cool, that was an easy fix of a non-existent problem ;D I converted my comment to an answer so that you can accept it and mark the question as solved this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `libfftw3-dev` installation is fine.

The problem is that `locate` doesn't perform a real live disk search but only a database lookup in some kind of file name database, by default `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`.

This database gets updated automatically every day by a cron-job running `updatedb`, but file system changes made after the last update are therefore of course not represented. Because of this, you should trigger an update manually using

```
sudo updatedb
```

after adding new or removing old files to get correct and up to date results from `locate`.